# Transform multiple properties of the same type to List of these properties in data class Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

In my app I'm retrieving data from json and unfortunately, It is written in such a way, that I can't straight away obtain a list. How can I transform my data class to consist of one property: **List< Itinerary >** which consists these 10 (or more) itineraries?

```
data class ItineraryData(
    val itinerary0: Itinerary,
    val itinerary1: Itinerary,
    val itinerary2: Itinerary,
    val itinerary3: Itinerary,
    val itinerary4: Itinerary,
    val itinerary5: Itinerary,
    val itinerary6: Itinerary,
    val itinerary7: Itinerary,
    val itinerary8: Itinerary,
    val itinerary9: Itinerary
),
```

**THE JSON**

```
"itinerary_data" : {
      "itinerary_0": {...},
      "itinerary_1": {...},
      "itinerary_2": {...},
      "itinerary_3": {...},
      "itinerary_4": {...},
      "itinerary_5": {...},
      "itinerary_6": {...},
      "itinerary_7": {...},
      "itinerary_8": {...},
      "itinerary_9": {...},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. Because the itineraries in the json are not in array format, so you can't get a Kotlin list out of it. One solution is to parse it as a `Map<String, Itinerary>` and then get the list of values from the map.

```
data class ItinerariesResponse(
    @Json(name = "itinerary_data")
    val itineraries: Map<String, Itinerary>
)
```

Then you can get the list of itineraries like this:

```
val response: ItinerariesResponse = yourApiCall();
val itineraries = response.itineraries.values();
```

Comment: I did this, logged the itineraries value and it's null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you log `response`? What does it contain?